# Countdown timer doesn't stop at 0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimer, nsuinteger

I have a timer which works perfectly if the timer is in the foreground. It decrements perfectly and stops at 0. However, when I tap the homebutton to go to the main screen, and then wait for the local notification to pop up, and then I tap the notification, the time interval turns into 4.2 billion (the limit for unsigned long int). Basically, it doesn't stop at 0. I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried making it a regular NSInteger and checking if the interval went below 0 but I got the same results.

```
-(IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender{
    if (!timer) {
        [startButton setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
       date = [NSDate date];
    } else {
        [startButton setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        anotherTimeInterval = testTask.timeInterval;
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

}

-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t
{
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date];
    if (testTask.timeInterval > 0){
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        NSUInteger seconds = (NSUInteger)round(anotherTimeInterval-interval);
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02u:%02u:%02u",
                            seconds / 3600, (seconds / 60) % 60, seconds % 60];
        testTask.timeInterval = seconds;
        timerLabel.text = string;
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"timer ended");
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
        [self timerExpired];
    }
}

-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    if (timer){
        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:testTask.timeInterval];
        localNotification.alertBody = @"Time is up";
        localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%02u` you're using in the `stringWithFormat:` parses the value as an unsigned int.

Also, and I think this is your problem, you're checking testTask.timeInterval in your `if` statement, but getting the number of seconds from the `interval` variable you get at the start of the method. 
So you're always checking the previous value, meaning you're always one second behind.

Edit:
You could do somehting like this:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date];
if (anotherTimeInterval-interval > 0){
    ...
}
```

That way, you check the *new* value instead of the old one.

Hope this helps

Comment: ok that makes sense...so are you saying i shouldnt check for the value of testtask.interval, but rather something else?